# ASP.NET WebForms in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-webcontrol

Is it possible to call normal ASPX pages with their normal life-cycle in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application? What about web controls and ajax.net toolkit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. Simply create your MVC application and add a new web forms page. Thats it.

Comment: This is the answer. Just created a new web form and added update panels and whatever i needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[Deploying ASP.NET MVC on ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx)

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

I recommend creating a WebForms project and using this NuGet package:

[AddMvc3ToWebForms](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms)

Comment: Wow very quick! But I need to do the opposite. Any tips on that?

Comment: What is the difference?  They will both run.

Comment: Tips? it is easier to create blank mvc2 application and import the webform based web into it... as far as i have experience

Comment: Well, there is a Nuget package that can do it for you.  See here: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AddMvc3ToWebForms

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, actually it's easier than expected.